# Creating a Line at a Length and Angle in WGS84 - Arcobjects

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, coordinate-system, wgs84

I need to draw a line at desired length(around 10-20 Km length) and a user entered angle. The map/data uses WGS84 coordinate system. So the measurement is geodesic.

Here are the methods that I tried.

1. **Find the point at an angle and distance.**

Obviously this will not work as the computation is planar and this works only at the equator region.

2. **IConstructGeodetic.ConstructGeodeticLineFromDistance method**

I called it like below and this seemed to be a promising method as it gave correct distances. But at certain locations, this method simply crashes with outofmemoryexception

```
ConstructGeodeticLineFromDistance(esriGeodeticType.esriGeodeticTypeGeodesic, FromPoint, lUnit, d,Azimuth, esriCurveDensifyMethod.esriCurveDensifyByLength, 0.01)
```

3. **Using the Equations found at [movable-type](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) website**

This equation also has distance issues at different parts of earth. If i draw a 10Km line sometimes it comes as 10, but sometimes its 9 Km. The method I converted to c# is below.

```c#
public static IPoint GetAtDistBearing(IPoint co, double distance, double brng)
{
    double lat1 = co.Y;
    double lon1 = co.X;
    double ER = 6374;
    double d = distance;    

    brng = ToRadians(brng);
    lat1 = ToRadians(lat1);
    lon1 = ToRadians(lon1);

    double lat2 = Math.Asin(Math.Sin(lat1) * Math.Cos(d / ER) + Math.Cos(lat1) * Math.Sin(d / ER) * Math.Cos(brng));
    double lon2 = lon1 + Math.Atan2(Math.Sin(brng) * Math.Sin(d / ER) * Math.Cos(lat1), Math.Cos(d / ER) - Math.Sin(lat1) * Math.Sin(lat2));

    lon2 = (lon2 + 3 * Math.PI) % (2 * Math.PI) - Math.PI;

    IPoint p = new PointClass();
    p.X = ToDegrees(lon2);
    p.Y = ToDegrees(lat2);

    return p;
}
```

I think I am missing something obvious. Hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Which version of ArcGIS are you using?  See also http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#f2d208bf-acdc-48f2-bf6b-271c2b4f9545.htm

Comment: @KirkKuykendall - It is Arc 10.3

Comment: @KirkKuykendall - Thanks for that url...made me think more spherical :)

Comment: @KirkKuykendall - so understood the densification parameter of IConstructGeodetic.ConstructLineFromDistance .. i was just putting in 0.01 without knowing what it was..now got it to work by setting it to distance divided by 10

Answer (score 1):

This model assumes the world is spherical, but earth's radius changes with the latitude.

If the distance covers about 1/10 of a degree, and Earth's radius ranges from 6353-6384km, then the error can be over 400m.

This might cause 10km to come out as 9km if you are aggressively rounding.